# React storage event doesn't get triggered on the tab that wrote to storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is detect when authentication changed (login/logout). My login form is in modal and there are some pages in my app that have minor differences when a user is logged in from when they're logged out. So I need to detect when that happens and refetch the pages' data to get updated information.

An example would be an `Article` page. You can upvote the article but you have to be logged in.

Now whenever the authentication changes I write the `token` and `user` objects to localStorage. So I thought I would use the `storage` event on the `Article` component and listen to `user` object change and refetch the data when it does change.

This is the code from my Article component that should detect the `storage` change (removed irrelevant code):

```
class Article extends Component {
  fetchData() {
    // fetch data
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
    window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
      console.log('storage fired');
      // this.fetchData();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove event listener
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Render article
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm on this page and log in from my modal and write the changes to the `storage`, the event doesn't fire. However, if I have another tab open on the same page, the event does fire there. So it works on all browser tabs, except the one where I'm actually logging in.

How would I go about solving this?

I'm also open to any other solutions to the problem. The problem being - detect an auth change and reload the page when it does change. I'm also writing the user and token objects to the redux store (if there's a nicer solution with redux maybe).

**Edit:**

I've recreated the issue with minimal code on this repository: https://github.com/d1am0nd/storage-problem

In order to run it, you have to start a local server in `dist` folder (say  localhost:3000). Then open 2 tabs and click the "Write to storage" button. An alert doesn't trigger on the current tab, but it does trigger on the other tab.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but usually all socket or event listeners I place in the constructor

Comment: I've tried moving it to the constructor and same happens. Gets triggered on other tabs, but not on current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior of this event.

> A StorageEvent is sent to a window when a storage area it has access to is changed within the context of another document.

Look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API